# Enabling/Disabling Toolbar-Command based on selection in ViewPart, not Perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, selection, toolbar

I have a perspective consisting of multiple `ViewPart`s. One of these `ViewPart`s has a command assigned using a `menuContribution` with `locationURI="toolbar:..."`.

The `ViewPart` with the Toolbar-Command only contains one Child (a `TreeView`) and does `this.getSite().setSelectionProvider(child)` in it's `createPartControl(Composite)`-Method.

The problem is, that when i click one of the other `ViewPart`s in my Perspective the Command gets disabled, but the selection does resist in the `TreeView`-Component. 
I guess the `enabledWhen`-Condition is not valid anymore, because the `selection`-Variable now points to stuff that resists in another ViewPart.

This distracts, because the Toolbar-Button should be activated, when a valid row in the `TreeView` is selected.

How do i tell my Core Expression, that it only should check the selection of the `ViewPart` the Toolbar resists in and not the global-selection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and what I ended up doing was implementing my own property tester. This is probably the easiest way, because the predefined `selection` variable will always point to the global selection.

Roughly, you will need to follow the steps below.

1. add `org.eclipse.core.expressions` plug-in to your dependency.
2. define an extension for `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point. This would look something like the following ([documentation link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_propertyTesters.html)):

   ```
   <extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
     <propertyTester
           class="your.package.TreeItemSelectionPropertyTester"
           id="your.package.treeItemSelectionPropertyTester"
           namespace="your.namespace"
           properties="itemSelected"
           type="java.lang.Object">
     </propertyTester>
   </extension>
   ```
3. Implement your PropertyTester code. As the above documentation says, the class should be public and should extend `org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester` class.

   ```
   public class CodeSelectionPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {
       @Override
       public boolean test(Object receiver, String property,
               Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
           if (property.equals("itemSelected")) {
               // write your own code to test
               // whether there is a valid selection...
           }

           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use the implemented property tester in your enabledWhen clause.

   ```
    <enabledWhen>
       <test
             property="your.namespace.itemSelected">
       </test>
    </enabledWhen>
   ```