# How to reactivate an icon after 3 seconds

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP GUI in which I want to do an icon "refresh": when the user click on it, it is disabled. After 3 second it is enabled again.

I would like to find **a way to do it withou thread**.

I followed this tutorial:
[Enabling/Disabling Toolbar-Command based on selection in ViewPart, not Perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272671/enabling-disabling-toolbar-command-based-on-selection-in-viewpart-not-perspecti)
It works but my problem is that I don't see how to make eclipse reactivate the button, without doing a TimerThread...

Any ideas?

Comment: why you don't want to use a thread ?

Comment: Because I think it's doable without. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: When the icon is clicked, the action will be executed in the Main/UI-Thread. When you don't use a Thread, the whole UI will be blocked for the 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Without a thread you could do it in a while loop:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long current = start;
long threeSecondsAsMillis = 3 * 1000;
long oneSecondsAsMillis = 1000;

while (current < start + threeSecondsAsMillis) {
    Thread.sleep(oneSecondsAsMillis);
    current += oneSecondsAsMillis;
}
// continue your work
```

Note, that this is a bad solution, as it will block your UI. Better solution would be to use Eclipse Job:

```
    Job job = new Job("") {

                @Override
                protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                    // note, that you are not in the UI-Thread anymore, but you must enable icon in the UI-Thread:


    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            // enable icon
            }
        });
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
 }
 };
job.schedule(3000);
```

As noted by greg-449, you can use also a UIJob:

```
UIJob job = new UIJob("") {

                @Override
                    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {


    // enable icon
                    return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }
            };
            job.schedule(3000);
```

Comment: Yes, if this operation is not gonna take much time and not gonna block UI, then sure.

Comment: A `UIJob` works the same as the `Job` you show, it just deals with doing the `Display.asyncExec` for you

Comment: UIJob is running inside of UI thread, so doing a long running operation (like data loading or something similar) will block UI and it will stop being responsive until the job is completed. For current case it sure may be a better idea to use a UIJob, if it is only about enabling something after 3 seconds.